# Использование несколько классов делегатов для QTableView PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtableview

При назначении методом `setitemdelegateforcolumn()` таблице(`TableView`) классов-делегатов двум различным столбцам "количество"(`QSpinBox`) и "дата поступления"(`QDateEdit`) приложение начинает вылетать.

При использовании делегатов по отдельности приложение работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class SpinBoxDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    editor = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent)
    return editor

def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
    value = index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
    try: value = int(value)
    except: value = 0
    editor.setValue(value)

def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, options, index):
    editor.setGeometry(options.rect)

def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
    value = str(editor.value())
    model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

class MyDateEditDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
    editor = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(parent)
    editor.setFrame(False)
    editor.setCalendarPopup(True) # Вместо стрелок вылезает календарь
    return editor

def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
    editor.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())

def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, options, index):
    editor.setGeometry(options.rect)

def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
    value = str(editor.dateTime().date().toPyDate())
    model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

class MyDelegateInTableView(QtWidgets.QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()  # Представление
    self.sim = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent=self.table)  # Модель
    today = str(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().date().toPyDate())

    myPCIntel = ['Intel® NUC NUC8i3BEK', 'Intel Core i3 8-го поколения (i3-8109U)',
                 'RAM - 8 GB (DDR4, частота 2400MHz)', 'M.2 NVMe SSD 512Гб', '3', today]
    myPCAMD = ['AMD Sempron', 'Процессор AMD Sempron 140', 'DDR3 2048MB 1333MHz Kingston',
               '1Tb Seagate Barracuda 7200.12', '5', today]
    for i in range(len(myPCIntel)):
        item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(myPCIntel[i])
        item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(myPCAMD[i])
        self.sim.appendColumn([item1, item2])
    self.sim.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
        ['Название', 'Процессор', 'Оперативная память', 'Постоянная память', 'Количество компьютеров', 'Дата поступления'])
    self.table.setModel(self.sim)

    # LAYOUT
    boxMain = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    boxMain.addWidget(self.table)
    self.setLayout(boxMain)

    # DELEGATE # Назначение делегатов столбцам таблицы
    self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(4, SpinBoxDelegate())
    self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(5, MyDateEditDelegate())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):                                # +++ Delegate

    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        if index.column() == 5:
            editor = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(parent)
            editor.setFrame(False)
            editor.setCalendarPopup(True) # Вместо стрелок вылезает календарь
            return editor
        elif index.column() == 4:
            editor = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent)
            return editor        

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if index.column() == 5:
            editor.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        elif index.column() == 4:
            value = index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
            try: value = int(value)
            except: value = 0
            editor.setValue(value)            

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, options, index):
        editor.setGeometry(options.rect)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if index.column() == 5:
            value = str(editor.dateTime().date().toPyDate())
            model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        elif index.column() == 4:
            value = str(editor.value())
            model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)


class MyDelegateInTableView(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()                     # Представление
        self.sim = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent=self.table)  # Модель
        today = str(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().date().toPyDate())

        myPCIntel = ['Intel® NUC NUC8i3BEK', 'Intel Core i3 8-го поколения (i3-8109U)',
                     'RAM - 8 GB (DDR4, частота 2400MHz)', 'M.2 NVMe SSD 512Гб', '3', today]
        myPCAMD = ['AMD Sempron', 'Процессор AMD Sempron 140', 'DDR3 2048MB 1333MHz Kingston',
                   '1Tb Seagate Barracuda 7200.12', '5', today]
        for i in range(len(myPCIntel)):
            item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(myPCIntel[i])
            item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(myPCAMD[i])
            self.sim.appendColumn([item1, item2])
        self.sim.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['Название', 'Процессор', 'Оперативная память', 'Постоянная память', 'Количество компьютеров', 'Дата поступления'])
        self.table.setModel(self.sim)

        # LAYOUT
        boxMain = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        boxMain.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(boxMain)

        # DELEGATE # Назначение делегатов столбцам таблицы
#        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(4, SpinBoxDelegate())
#        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(5, MyDateEditDelegate())
        delegate = Delegate(self)                                              # +++
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(4, delegate)                       # +++
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(5, delegate)                       # +++



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windowExample = MyDelegateInTableView()
    windowExample.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @НикитаСолоницын мой ответ отвечает на ваш вопрос?

Comment: да! спасибо!) только я думал что можно создавать на одну таблицу несколько классов делегатов, и долго искал ответ на это

Comment: @НикитаСолоницын   Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, ваш вариант в сущности и так рабочий. Для того, чтобы программа не вылетала, достаточно в момент назначения делегатов столбцам таблицы, передать `self` в создаваемые экземпляры классов делегатов.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class SpinBoxDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        editor = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        try: value = int(value)
        except: value = 0
        editor.setValue(value)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, options, index):
        editor.setGeometry(options.rect)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = str(editor.value())
        model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

class MyDateEditDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        editor = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(parent)
        editor.setFrame(False)
        editor.setCalendarPopup(True) # Вместо стрелок вылезает календарь
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, options, index):
        editor.setGeometry(options.rect)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = str(editor.dateTime().date().toPyDate())
        model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

class MyDelegateInTableView(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()  # Представление
        self.sim = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent=self.table)  # Модель
        today = str(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().date().toPyDate())

        myPCIntel = ['Intel® NUC NUC8i3BEK', 'Intel Core i3 8-го поколения (i3-8109U)',
                     'RAM - 8 GB (DDR4, частота 2400MHz)', 'M.2 NVMe SSD 512Гб', '3', today]
        myPCAMD = ['AMD Sempron', 'Процессор AMD Sempron 140', 'DDR3 2048MB 1333MHz Kingston',
                   '1Tb Seagate Barracuda 7200.12', '5', today]
        for i in range(len(myPCIntel)):
            item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(myPCIntel[i])
            item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(myPCAMD[i])
            self.sim.appendColumn([item1, item2])
        self.sim.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['Название', 'Процессор', 'Оперативная память', 'Постоянная память', 
             'Количество компьютеров', 'Дата поступления'])
        self.table.setModel(self.sim)

        # LAYOUT
        boxMain = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        boxMain.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(boxMain)

        # DELEGATE # Назначение делегатов столбцам таблицы
        # **Сюда добавили self**
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(4, SpinBoxDelegate(self))
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(5, MyDateEditDelegate(self))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windowExample = MyDelegateInTableView()
    windowExample.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```